# Shortcut for @extend in SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

Is there a shortcut for `@extend` in SASS such as `=` for `@mixin` or `+` for `@include`?

Comment: This sounds like a feature request for the authors of Sass, not an actual question.

Comment: Why did you downvoted this? This was a question if there is a shortcut for this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could work by adding a custom function as described [here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions)
(I am at work and not able to test it)

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def *(string)
      assert_type string, :String
      Sass::Script::String.new(string.value.sub('*', '@require')
  end
  declare :*, :args => [:string]
end
```